# when does currentBuild.changeSets in Jenkins gets filled?

Tags: jenkins

Some background: The project I'm working on is in SVN. Very very large. A lot of tests are running on Jenkins. I want to implement a new tests which should be executed only if files in certain directory have been changed.

The idea that I had was:

- to trigger the job using a pollSCM every ten minutes
- check the files in currentBuild.changeSets. If a file contains the directory, continue.
- Only then I do a full checkout of the repository, compile, and run the tests.

But before I write the code, I was wondering when does  currentBuild.changeSets? Will it have the required information when triggered by a pollSCM? I could not find this in the documentation

Yes, this could be done in a better way using git and hooks and other tools but that's what I have right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be set after any `checkout` steps (or derivatives of `checkout` such as `git` or `svn`).

So for instance:

```
println(currentBuild.changeSets) // should print an empty set

checkout(scm)

println(currentBuild.changeSets) // should print out any changes in the current build
```

Comment: I get this as output:
hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList@517831da